# There is a compatibility range mismatch between the Web server and database

Tags: 2013

I have this error:

```
There is a compatibility range mismatch between the Web server and database "AppDevelopment_Content", and connections to the data have been blocked to due to this incompatibility. This can happen when a content database has not been upgraded to be within the compatibility range of the Web server, or if the database has been upgraded to a higher level than the web server. The Web server and the database must be upgraded to the same version and build level to return to compatibility range.
```

What I want to do: 
Create my first hello world app

What I did

1. I created a new web application with a new content database with the name above

   1. I created a site collection with site coll administrator to my username.

Then I did all of this:
http://blog.mannualag.com/2013/03/07/nuisances-of-starting-developing-apps-for-sharepoint-2013/

```
After pressing F5 on VS 2013 I got 
Error   1   Error occurred in deployment step 'Uninstall app for SharePoint': Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: http://be-appsdev003.xx.xx.xxx.com/. Make sure that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project, update the Site URL property of the project.
        0   0   HelloWorldApp
```

When I check the logs I see:

```
There is a compatibility range mismatch between the Web server and database "AppDevelopment_Content", and connections to the data have been blocked to due to this incompatibility. This can happen when a content database has not been upgraded to be within the compatibility range of the Web server, or if the database has been upgraded to a higher level than the web server. The Web server and the database must be upgraded to the same version and build level to return to compatibility range.
```

I checked with the DBA and all permissions are set as in the article, so the error is more due to compatibiloity range mismatch, but

How do I fix that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to solve it my self.  Posted the solution on my own blog

http://levalencia.wordpress.com/?p=273&preview=true

Today, I had this error when I was trying to deploy a simple Hello World App for first time.

I tried everything on this blog and still didnt work.

http://blog.mannualag.com/2013/03/07/nuisances-of-starting-developing-apps-for-sharepoint-2013/#

Guys, let me tell you what my problem was.

When I first started I was developing with the farm account, suddently when I was trying to deploy VS says that you can not use the system account to deploy apps. Read the link above.

So, I logged in with my account, and the mistake was this:  I created the app management service application and the new web application with my username, yes its farm admin, yes its local administrator.

The problem is the farm account has a server role of db creation and security admin, this means that when this account tries to create databases, it will also make the security adjustments needed on the databases for the configuration to be correct.

Because I tried to do this with a normal user account which has no Sql Server roles, then the Content DB was created, and the app management service application was created too.

However, it didnt set up the security on the databases the right way

After following the post above, and checking the logs with the dba we saw this error :

There is a compatibility range mismatch between the Web server and database

We double checked permissions and they were all set correctly.

Solution:

1. Delete the app management service application.
2. Delete the new web application content database.

Fortunately it was a development environment, after recreating these 2 things, the app was succesfully deployed using F5 on Vs 2012.

Comment: It was a workaround instead of solution

Comment: You should post the solution or workaround here, not link to your private blog just to drive traffic to it!

Comment: I decide how I want to paste the solution.

Comment: You sure do, I just pasted the important bit in in the meantime :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to upgrade the database with PSConfig from command-line:

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force
```

Comment: Has anyone tried this answer? What's the result in having performed this command?

Comment: This is what you normally do after applying a CU so yes, many of us has tried it. What it does is update schema definitions and other things i the DB and in other SharePoint files to make it up to date after an ugrade

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

I setup a routing web application to make SharePoint Apps work. The routing web application app pool account needs SPDataAccess permission on every content database that plans on using apps.